# How to show Empty Message when RecyclerView is empty?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

> I am loading some contents from `Firebase` and also using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` .

[image]

> This is the Function which shows data from Firebase successfully :

```
    public void showNotifications() {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications");
    databaseReference.keepSynced(true);
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NotificationModel>()
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications"), NotificationModel.class)
            .build();
    notifRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    notificationAdaper = new NotificationAdaper(options, NotificationActivity.this);
    notifRecyclerView.setAdapter(notificationAdaper);
    checkEmpty();  //will show empty image when recyclerView is empty
}
```

> This is my checkEmpty() method :

```
    private void checkEmpty() {
    if (notificationAdaper.getItemCount() == 0) {
        Log.e("Item count", String.valueOf(notificationAdaper.getItemCount()));
        no_notif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        no_notif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

> Here is the UI code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.devapps.NotificationActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Notifications"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/no_notif"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/nonotification" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notifRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> The Empty Image Placeholder is always visible even when there is an Item in Firebase Database. How to fix it.

> Everytime i am getting   `E/Item count: 0` even when there is an Item in Firebase Database.

Comment: And for further more specific answer we need to see you ui code

Comment: added, please have a look @KamalNayan

Comment: Check the answer..... I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

May be you are just altering the visibility of empty view(which you are using to notify user) and not hiding the other views. Like you have recycler view so you need to hide that and view empty message otherwise the message view may be behind the recycler view and hence it is not visible.

### Solution

Hide other views on that particular screen

```
 private void checkEmpty() {
if (notificationAdaper.getItemCount() == 0) {
    Log.e("Item count", String.valueOf(notificationAdaper.getItemCount()));
    no_notif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   notifRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

} else {
    no_notif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   notifRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

}

NOTE: `notifRecyclerView` is the id of recycler view...... I have used it for reference..... if you have declared recycler view with another name in the file , then use that name in lieu of `notifRecyclerView`

Comment: I didnt get it, Why should I hide other View, when there is no Data/Item, the  RecyclerView itself hides

Comment: How it itself hides?

Comment: Sorry to bother you Sir, but your answer doesnt explain anything, please add some code example as well

Comment: It is on the screen but it has no data so you are no recognizing it.

Comment: No problem Sainita...... you are not bothering ,we are here to help...Feel free to ask

Comment: I have updated the answer..... let me know if it doesn't work .

Comment: even if there are items in recyclerView , the message is still visible.

Comment: What is the count in log? =>   Log.e("Item count", String.valueOf(notificationAdaper.getItemCount()));

Comment: I have already mentioned when i posted the Question, please have a look at the question

Comment: are the items shown in recycler view...... because if the log is being printed it means your getItemCount returns 0 and if condition is being executed so there is no problem with the check function or the code handling with visibility

Comment: You need to review the getItemCount()

Comment: Thats What confuses me as well, getItemCount() is printing 0, even after that the Items from Firebase are being showed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get Recycler View Count

recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();